# Query to find 2 cheapest items sum value of which gives 3000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Products:

```
ProductName          Price  
straight jeans       1500  
slim jeans           2500  
Denim jacket         3000  
Denim shorts         800  
Skinny jeans         1700  
loose Jeans          2100  
mom Jeans            2800  
wide jeans           1850  
distressed jeans     1100  
bootcut jeans        1350
```

For purchased two different things with a total value of 3000 or more, they give a third as a gift.
I need a SQL query to spend minimum on two things, and take third as the most expensive.

The only thing I've come up with is to go through all possible combinations and find the cheapest combination that over 3000.

```
WITH Products_sum AS (
  SELECT p1.ProductName AS ProductName1, p2.ProductName AS ProductName2, p1.Price + p2.Price AS TotalPrice
  FROM products p1
  JOIN products p2
    ON p1.ProductName < p2.ProductName
)
SELECT top 1 ProductName1, ProductName2, TotalPrice
FROM Products_sum
WHERE TotalPrice >= 3000
order by TotalPrice asc
```

I'm expecting answer like:

```
bootcut jeans        1350
Skinny jeans         1700
Denim jacket         3000
```

But don't know how to do exactly like that.

Comment: You can use `UNPIVOT`

Comment: You might want to look into CPlex and OPL. But maybe that's bringing a cannon to a fist fight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued from where you left it and compose the expected result.

Converted as cte the top pair of products and the most expensive.

Combine the final resultset with union statement.

```
WITH Products_sum AS (
  SELECT p1.ProductName AS ProductName1
    , p2.ProductName AS ProductName2
    , p1.Price + p2.Price AS TotalPrice
    , p1.Price Price1
    , p2.Price Price2
  FROM products p1
  JOIN products p2
    ON p1.ProductName < p2.ProductName
),
topProducts as (SELECT top 1 ProductName1, ProductName2, Price1, Price2
FROM Products_sum
WHERE TotalPrice >= 3000
order by TotalPrice asc),
moreExpensive as (
    select top 1 ProductName, Price
    from products 
    order by price desc
)
select productName, Price from(
select 1 as pos, ProductName1 ProductName, Price1 Price from topProducts
union
select 2, ProductName2 , Price2 from topProducts
union
select 3, ProductName, Price
from moreExpensive )q
order by pos
```

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation in addition to working code.

Comment: @DaleK at least he beat me to it with a minute ;)

Comment: @DaleK I just realized that my answer was not completely right, editing it.

Comment: so, 15 minutes then, and explanation included :D

Comment: @Horaciux notify me as well, so I can upvote it if it looks good

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.ProductName, p1.Price,
       p2.ProductName, p2.Price,
       p3.ProductName, p3.Price
FROM Products p1
JOIN Products p2
on p1.ProductName < p2.ProductName
JOIN Products p3
ON p2.ProductName < p3.ProductName AND 
       p1.Price + p2.Price + p3.Price > 3000
LEFT JOIN Products nonexistent
ON NOT (nonexistent.ProductName IN (p1.ProductName, p2.ProductName, p3.ProductName)) AND
   p1.Price + p2.Price + nonexistent.Price > 3000 AND
   nonexistent.Price < p3.Price
WHERE nonexistent.ProductName IS NULL
```

We

- select every (`p1`, `p2`, `p3`) tuples
- where their name differs
- their price is greater than 3000
- and there doesn't exist any `nonexistent` record that would differ from these three, would yield a smaller price with `p1` and `p2` than `p3` but still above 3000

Comment: Just to mention `GREATEST()` only works on SQL Server 2022

Comment: @Horaciux I have completely rewritten my answer, as it was not quite correct earlier